# Automatically open mounted volumes in Path Finder

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mount

I may just be missing some simple setting, but if I mount a volume in Path Finder, it never switches to show me the contents of the volume.  I have to manually click the volume in the sidebar.  Is there a way to have it immediately switch to that volume after I mount it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not switching but show in a new window.
Preferences->Browser->Open mounted volumes in new Window

Comment: That Preference no longer exists in Path Finder 7.3.3